# Why the wordpress theme uploaded in zip is treated as new instead of triggering update?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I have a wordpress theme I'm working on. When I deploy the theme to the server I pack it into a zip and upload using WP admin. Assuming this theme is already installed I expect an update to happen but WP treats it as new and proposes to activate the uploaded theme. What am I doing wrong?

Unfortunately, I have no (s)FTP or SSH access to the server.

It is worth mentioning that metadata in `style.css` is the same (hence theme name, author etc).

WP version is 6.0.2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the name of the zip file the same?

Comment: @MosheGross, yes always the same: [theme-name]-theme.zip

Comment: It could the case when the `[theme-name]-theme.zip` file exists in the media library, so when you again upload the same theme zip it comes as `[theme-name]-theme-1.zip` and is treated as a new theme. if you think how `[theme-name]-theme.zip` went to media lib, it's because you maybe uploaded the theme but didn't replace it in the past so it remains in the media library. Search the zip file by it's name in media library and delete that file first.

Comment: @VijayHardaha, that totally makes sense. Thanks a lot I will check if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This question was essentially answered by [Vijay Hardaha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11848895/vijay-hardaha) in the comments, I am posting an answer to make the solution more visible and organise information after dealing with it myself.

The issue occurs if a file named `[theme-name].zip` already exists in the Media Library. This can be caused by either:

1. An unsuccessful theme upload (for example due to reloading the page while theme upload is being processed)
2. Manually uploading this file to media library

Since Wordpress uses the Media Library as a temporary directory for theme upload, it adds a sequential number to the filename, if a file with the same filename already exists (`[theme-name]-1.zip`, `[theme-name]-2.zip`, etc.).

This causes the attempted theme update to be treated as uploading a new theme, with a directory `[theme-name]-[number]`.

To solve this issue simply remove the `[theme-name].zip` file from your media library.